# Names of Allah Is it written Correctly

Tags: allah, names

Can we write Allah's Name, Without "Al" before that Name? Example is writing "Qayyoom" instead of "Al-Qayyoom" This question arise because somebody has written only "Qayyoom" and mention that it is a Name of Allah.

Answer (score 1):

Qayyoom is an adjective, it is not a private name. But Al-Qayyoom is a private adjective which refers only to Allah. Just like Ar-Rahman, Ar-Rahim, Al-Bari etc.

Ilah is the word in Arabic meaning god. You can claim that Zeus was a god, or Uzza. This won't be wrong literally. But Al-Ilah (Allah) means "one true god". It is like "The God", which is the one, everyone understands that you are not mentioning Zeus or Uzza.

Qayyoom is of the same type with merciful, but when we say All Merciful, we mean Allah.

Thus, you should put **Al**, if you want to refer to Allah.

Answer (score 0):

If you speaking Persian or Urdu you can omit the article. If you are speaking Arabic you do not omit it.

Comment: I have mentioned my question only about writing Allah's names in English